# Updating HTML field filled with a Django value real-time

Tags: javascript, html, django

Say I have two form fields and another HTML paragraph that is basically just a Django value.

Number A:

`<input ...>`

Number B:

`<input ...>`

`<p>{{ sum }}</p>`

I want sum to update "real time" (i.e. after both numbers were input, the sum will be computed and input automatically by the system).

I have no idea where to start, I think it has something to do with some sort of javascript, but I have no idea how to link anything JS to Django and vice-versa.

Comment: This has nothing to do with django. Django is only involved when it comes from the server. You could make an Ajax call, but that would be ridiculous. Just do it on the client side with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need add them in javascript but after add it only have on the browser side, you need to call ajax call I give link for how to call ajax in django

```
<input type='number' id='val1'/>
<input type='number' id='val2'/>
<input type='number' id='answer'/>
```

I geuss you have above three text

After creat blur on `val2`
In body of blur event call ajax with django
[Ajax call in django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)